# Where can I get detailed documentation about Xebium?

Tags: fitnesse

I am trying to use Xebium for Acceptance testing. I have added couple of test cases recorded with SeleniumIDE. For the failed cases, I would like to display custom reports with details about the error in the result page.

I have gone thru the Xebium site - http://xebia.github.io/Xebium/ but not much information to solve the issue.

Is it possible to customize the test reports and display errors in Xebium? Or is there anyother alternative which is based on FitNesse Framework.

Comment: I don't know what you want to customize. I've developed my own fixtures to test websites using Selenium (but not using SeleniumIDE): https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures. I believe it has more detailed error reports (screenshots and HTML page source) when things don't go as expected. An example with an error can be found at: http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.BrowserTests.HeuristicVsTechnicalSelectors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, We cannot customize the report. 
You can get the test history for all test runs under **Tools -> Test History** section.

If there are any errors, you can click on the execution log which will have detailed log information with info and error messages for the particular test run.